# Test Class : Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature

Tags: apex, unit-test, customsetting

I have attempted to write my first test apex class, and although it looks correct when i try and save i get the following error

> "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: getPolicy() at line 74
>   column 37".

I have been looking at this class for the last 2 hours trying to work out what the problem is, however i am keep drawing a blank.

```
/********************************************************************
 *DM_MarketingCloudPolicyController_Test
 *
 *Test class for DM_MarketingCloudPolicyController
 *
 *Author:
 *Created: 14/09/2015
 *The @isTest class annotation indicates this class only contains test methods.
 *Classes defined with the @isTest annotation do not count against the organization 
 *size limit for all Apex scripts.See the Apex Language Reference for more information
 *about Testing and Code Coverage. Look @ BG coding standards if any doubts 
 ********************************************************************/

@isTest 
private class  DM_MarketingCloudPolicyController_Test{
static testMethod void DM_MarketingCloudPolicyController_Test(){

/*
*  Test Accept & Decline of Marketing Cloude policy
*/

        Profile prof1 = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile  WHERE Name = 'System Administrator'];


        User user1 = new User();
        user1.FirstName = 'Daniel';
        user1.LastName = 'Mason';
        user1.Email = 'daniel.mason@schroders.com';
        user1.Username = 'daniel.mason@schroders.com';
        user1.Alias = 'DMaso';
        user1.CommunityNickname = 'DMaso';
        user1.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles';
        user1.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
        user1.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
        user1.ProfileId = prof1.Id;
        user1.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
        user1.Marketing_Cloud_Acceptance_Date__c = null;
        insert user1;

//Setup Custom Setting for profile
        Data_Policy_Settings__c dps = new Data_Policy_Settings__c();
        dps.Show_Marketing_Policy__c = true;
        dps.SetupOwnerId = prof1.Id;

//Create Test Policy
        Data_Policy__c dp1 = new Data_Policy__c();
        dp1.Name = 'Test Data Policy';
        dp1.Start_Date__c = date.today();
        dp1.MarketingCloudPolicyText__c = 'Everyone Loves creating test classes ...';
        insert dp1;

        system.assertEquals(1, [SELECT Count() FROM User WHERE email = 'daniel.mason@schroders.com' LIMIT 1]);

        PageReference pageRef = Page.DataPolicyPage;


        System.runAs(user1){
        test.startTest();
        DM_MarketingCloudPolicyController controllerInstance = new DM_MarketingCloudPolicyController();
        boolean redirect = controllerInstance.getRedirect();

        test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        DM_MarketingCloudPolicyController controller = new DM_MarketingCloudPolicyController();

//Declining VF Page  
        PageReference logout = controller.closePopupDecline();
        system.assertEquals('/secur/logout.jsp',logout.getURL());

//Accepting VF Page
        controller.closePopupAccept();
        user1 = [SELECT Marketing_Cloud_Acceptance_Date__c FROM User WHERE email = 'daniel.mason@schroders.com'LIMIT 1];

        system.assertEquals(date.today(),user1.Marketing_Cloud_Acceptance_Date__c);
        Data_Policy__c dataPolicy = getPolicy();
        system.assertEquals(true,dataPolicy != null);
        test.stopTest();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my controller class

```
   /********************************************************************
 * DM_MarketingCloudPolicyController
 *
 * Controller class for MarketingCloudPolicyPage
 * 
 * Author: Daniel Mason
 * Created: 14/09/2015
 * add et4ae5__ExactTargetForAppExchangeUser__c = True logic userloggedin
 * 
 ********************************************************************/

public class DM_MarketingCloudPolicyController{

    Id uid; 
    User loggedInUser;

    public DM_MarketingCloudPolicyController(){
        uid = UserInfo.getUserId();
        loggedInUser = [SELECT Id, Marketing_Cloud_Acceptance_Date__c 
              FROM User
              WHERE Id = :uid
              LIMIT 1];
    } 

    public PageReference closePopupAccept() { 
        // Method to write back data policy acceptance date to user on accept
        loggedInUser.Marketing_Cloud_Acceptance_Date__c = date.today();
        update loggedInUser;        
        PageReference p = new PageReference('/home/home.jsp');
        p.setRedirect(true);      
        return p;
    } 

    public PageReference closePopupDecline() { 
        // Method to logout user afer decline 
        PageReference p = new PageReference('/secur/logout.jsp');
        p.setRedirect(true);      
        return p; 
    }

    public static Data_Policy__c getPolicy(){
        // Method to obtain data policy text
        Data_Policy__c dp = [SELECT Id, Name, Start_Date__c, MarketingCloudPolicyText__c 
                             FROM Data_Policy__c
                             LIMIT 1];

        return dp;
    }

   public boolean getRedirect(){
        // Method to determine show popup
        boolean redirect = false;     
        Data_Policy__c dp = getPolicy(); 
        Data_Policy_Settings__c dps = Data_Policy_Settings__c.getInstance(UserInfo.getProfileId());            
        if(dps.Show_Marketing_Policy__c == true && (loggedInUser.Marketing_Cloud_Acceptance_Date__c == null && loggedInUser.et4ae5__ExactTargetForAppExchangeUser__c == True || loggedInUser.Marketing_Cloud_Acceptance_Date__c.addYears(1) < date.today() || loggedInUser.Marketing_Cloud_Acceptance_Date__c < dp.Start_Date__c)){                              
            redirect = true;
        } 
        return redirect;
     }}
```

Comment: As the error clearly saying, I can't see a `getPolicy()` method in this class. Did you check for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's in this line

```
Data_Policy__c dataPolicy = getPolicy();
```

seeing as this is a test class, I am guessing this is a method in the DM_MarketingCloudPolicyController class.  Since it is a controller method, you need to call the method on the instance of the controller you have already created.  I believe if you adjust the line to this, it should work

```
Data_Policy__c dataPolicy = controller.getPolicy();
```

> **EDIT**

If it is a static method, then try calling it directly on the class rather than an instance of the class

```
Data_Policy__c dataPolicy = DM_MarketingCloudPolicyController.getPolicy();
```

Comment: if i change that line i get the following error Compile Error: Static methods cannot be invoked through an object instance: getPolicy() at line 74 column 37

Comment: if i change getPolicy(); to controller.getPolicy();  i get  the following error Compile Error: Static methods cannot be invoked through an object instance: getPolicy() at line 74 column 37

Comment: oh, if its a static method then you call it on the class itself, and not an instance of the class.  See the edit to my answer

Comment: No problem, glad it worked :)

Comment: Well the test class passed and my code has 95% coverage, however i was expecting a certain reasult and this didnt happen. Hmm

Comment: I think my controller class isnt executing as it should.  I am trying to say if Marketing_Cloud_Acceptance_Date__c is blank and et4ae5__ExactTargetForAppExchangeUser__c is ticked, then show me visual force page

Comment: ask a new question describing the desired outcome and what is happening.

Comment: Thanks Chris :) New question posted. Really appreciate your help